# Шифрование на Android и c#

Tags: android, c#, шифрование

есть шифрование на c# и требуется сделать аналогичное на android.
Пробовал по разному вот к чему пришел:
на c#

```
var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
fileStream.Read( salt, 0, SaltSize );
// initialize algorithm with salt
var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes( password, salt );
var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes( rijndael.BlockSize / 8 );//128/8 = 16
rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes( rijndael.KeySize / 8 );//256/8 = 32           
using( var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream( fileStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )
{
---- дальше не важно
```

и на андроид

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
byte[] Salt = new byte[8];
r.nextBytes(Salt);
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), Salt, 1000, 128));
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(tmp.getEncoded());//128/8 = 16
tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), Salt, 1000, 256));
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(bbb, "AES");//256/8 = 32
Cipher rijndael = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
rijndael.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,iv);
```

и при шифрование выходит разный результат
пример результата на андроид

```
IV = 84, 113, -97, 65, 36, -2, -67, -7, 34, 91, 109, 79, 77, 36, 112, 92
Key = 84, 113, -97, 65, 36, -2, -67, -7, 34, 91, 109, 79, 77, 36, 112, 92, -82, 18, 14, 99, -113, -61, 75, 68, -41, -34, 30, 77, 86, 35, 58, 46
```

а на c#

```
IV = 84, 113, -97, 65, 36, -2, -67, -7, 34, 91, 109, 79, 77, 36, 112, 92
Key = -82, 18, 14, 99, -113, -61, 75, 68, -41, -34, 30, 77, 86, 35, 58, 46, -90, 61, 106, -1, -117, 56, 107, 8, -109, -30, -119, -22, 77, 103, -17, 127
```

в итоге вектор совпадает, а вот ключ почему-то совпадает только на половину, что я делаю не так? 
P.S. я знаю что вектор и ключ каждый раз разные, я привёл только пример их значений.

Comment: SaltSize в c# у меня равен 8 если что..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил код на андроиде на такой:

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
byte[] Salt = new byte[8];
r.nextBytes(Salt);
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), Salt, 1000, 384));
byte[] data = secretKey.getEncoded();
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
System.arraycopy(data, 16, keyBytes, 0, 32);
System.arraycopy(data, 0, ivBytes, 0, 16);
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);//128/8 = 16
Log.d("array",Arrays.toString(iv.getIV()));
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");//256/8 = 32
Cipher rijndael = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
rijndael.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,iv);
```

нужно было просто создавать ключ один раз длиной в 384 бита, и делить его